# video play by getting url from metadata in vuforia cloud recgnization

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-video-player, qualcomm

Hi All I want to play video on target recognize, and the video url from metadata in cloud where i have given in json format.

i did this in my onQCARUpdate(State state) method....

```
if (finder.getResultCount() > 0)
        {
            TargetSearchResult result = finder.getResult(0);
            String metaResult = result.getMetaData();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Detected:" + metaResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(metaResult);
                String video = jsonObject.getString("videolink").toString();
                for (int i = 0;i < mMovieName[i].length();i++){
                    mVideoPlayerHelper[i].load(video, VideoPlayerHelper.MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE,true,mSeekPosition[i]);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Check if this target is suitable for tracking:
            if (result.getTrackingRating() > 0)
            {
                Trackable trackable = finder.enableTracking(result);

                //if (mExtendedTracking)
                    trackable.startExtendedTracking();
                //Toast.makeText(this,"Detected Name"+trackable.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

But it's not working, while recognizing target , it is showing only loading icon on surface, then nothing happens. Please suggest me how to achieve this

Comment: Check your Vuforia logs that are related to the video player and post them here if you need some more help. You have to make sure the video is playable on texture.

Comment: Thanks for replying ac0de, Now it's working fine.

Comment: How you got working?